# Is this a correct way to preload an image in Javascript / Jquery (with animation)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, preload

Im' trying to display a basic animation while an image loads, in html.

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
      //display the (small image) animation
      var preloader = new Image();
      preloader.src = 'img/preload.gif';
      $('#myDiv').append(preloader);

      //load big image and hide peload animation when finished
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () { $(preloader).hide(); preloader = null; } ;
      img.src = 'img/bigImage.jpg';
      $('#myDiv').append(img);
```

I'm not sure that is correct: although it works in my browser, the small animation is always loaded, even if the big image has already been loaded and is in cache. Is there a way to de-activate this, or think or another way to handle the preload of an image with a small animation?

Thanks

Comment: You can start a 100ms timeout and then check whether the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var preloader = new Image(),
    img       = new Image(),
    div       = document.getElementById('myDiv');

img.onload = function () {
    preloader = null; 
    div.innerHTML = '';
    div.appendChild(this);
};

img.src = 'img/bigImage.jpg';

// if it's not in cache or not loaded (has no size), show the preloader
if (! (img.complete || img.width+img.height > 0) ) {
    preloader.src = 'img/preload.gif';
    div.innerHTML = '';
    div.appendChild(preloader);
}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed! Thanks

Comment: I'd just like to note that something nice about this is that it doesn't cause the browser to check the cached status of an image resource when you'd do it by say, re-assigning the `src` attribute of an `img` to another URL. E.g. `var i = new Image(); i.src = 'http://path.to/img.jpg'`. Which helped me as I searched for a solution to just that.